Cloudflare Workers, how can I receive json from a page and send it somewhere else?
I would like to make a simple script that receives json on a page and headers, and redirects them to an external url, however, I am not able to do this using request. I tried to do something like this:
export default {
  async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
    const url = 'http:://myurl.com'
    const modfRequest = new Request(url, request)
    return new Response('Test');
  }
};

But nothing happens
